# How does bet365 real time live score work?

Tags: stream, real-time-data

So I am very fascinated about the bet365 real time match updates.

I m impressed how they have managed to show the attack and the defense as well as the real time ball passing stats. I really want to know more on how this work and is it possible to implement a similar.

Could someone help ??

[image]

Answer (score 0):

All live informations about match has bet365 from external services, that provide those informations. There are many services, that provide those data (for example betradar)